# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am getting the below error while releasing and pushing the gem. I tried installing it multiple times. Ruby Version is 2.2.9

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
 Unknown command bump

 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
  Unknown command release
```

I am running from the script and the script has the following lines:-

```
bundle install --deployment
gem install release -v '~> 0.4.0'
bundle exec gem release --tag --host http://rubygems/
gem install bump -v 0.8.0
bundle exec gem bump --push
```

Following is the log

```
Installing ri documentation for release-0.4.0
Done installing documentation for highline, visionmedia-commander, release after 3 seconds
3 gems installed
**ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
 Unknown command release**
Successfully installed bump-0.8.0
Parsing documentation for bump-0.8.0
Installing ri documentation for bump-0.8.0
Done installing documentation for bump after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
 **ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
  Unknown command bum**p
```

Added the dependency in Gemfile. Below is the Gemfile

```
  source 'http://rubygems'
  gem 'bump', '~> 0.8.0'
  gem 'release', '~> 0.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the source of rubygems is not defined properly. You may try updating source in Gemfile from 'http://rubygems' to 'https://rubygems.org'.

Comment: I tried changing the source. But it is not working. Giving the same error